# How can I make my column scrollable in Flutter?

Tags: listview, dart, flutter

I tried using `new Listview` but don't know what was going wrong in it - it always used to show some error like "expected 1 argument, but entered 0" even if I wrote shrinkwrap to true.

Removing Column also didn't work for me.

And I tried searching for some solutions on the internet, as I am still learning this language. I am not able to figure out the correct way to write it.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignupPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignupPageState createState() => _SignupPageState();
}

class _SignupPageState extends State<SignupPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        body: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 100.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                      child: Text(
                        'Signup',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 80.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(260.0, 105.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                      child: Text(
                        '.',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 80.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.green),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 35.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Full Name',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.grey),
                            // hintText: 'EMAIL',
                            // hintStyle: ,
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green))),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                      TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Email Address ',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.grey),
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green))),
                        obscureText: true,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                      TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Confirm Email Address ',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.grey),
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green))),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                      TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Password',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.grey),
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green))),
                        obscureText: true,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                      TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Phone Number ',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.grey),
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green))),
                        obscureText: true,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 50.0),
                      Container(
                          height: 40.0,
                          child: Material(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                            shadowColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                            color: Colors.green,
                            elevation: 7.0,
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {},
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  'SIGNUP',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          )),
                      SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                      Container(
                        height: 40.0,
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  style: BorderStyle.solid,
                                  width: 1.0),
                              color: Colors.transparent,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text('Go Back',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontFamily: 'Montserrat')),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
                )
            ]));
  }
}
```

Comment: Easiest way - wrap your `Column` in `SingleChildScrollView` )

Comment: no, it doesn't works .... shows error (that "Too many positional arguments")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have some issues with parentheses mismatch. Depending on your editor, there are many great Dart & Flutter plugins which can help. I pasted your code into a new Flutter project, removed the rogue parenthesis, and change the Scaffold body to ListView. It yields the behavior you ask for. Below is this code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignupPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignupPageState createState() => _SignupPageState();
}

class _SignupPageState extends State<SignupPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        body: ListView(
            // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 100.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                      child: Text(
                        'Signup',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 80.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(260.0, 105.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                      child: Text(
                        '.',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 80.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.green),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 35.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Full Name',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.grey),
                            // hintText: 'EMAIL',
                            // hintStyle: ,
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green))),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                      TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Email Address ',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.grey),
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green))),
                        obscureText: true,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                      TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Confirm Email Address ',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.grey),
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green))),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                      TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Password',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.grey),
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green))),
                        obscureText: true,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                      TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Phone Number ',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.grey),
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green))),
                        obscureText: true,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 50.0),
                      Container(
                        height: 40.0,
                        child: Material(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                          shadowColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                          color: Colors.green,
                          elevation: 7.0,
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {},
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                'SIGNUP',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                      Container(
                        height: 40.0,
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  style: BorderStyle.solid,
                                  width: 1.0),
                              color: Colors.transparent,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text('Go Back',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontFamily: 'Montserrat')),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
              ),
            ]
        )
     );
  }
}
```

Going forward, I would suggest using drtfmt to help with code format consistency. I noticed that indentations were inconsistent as well as the use of trailing commas was inconsistent. As you are learning the language, using extensions, linters, and formatters will really help! Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for getting me a solution, yes that might be the problem of closing brackets. But still, I am facing some issues, my app crashes everytime when this page loads

Comment: cause: null pointer dereference then some backtrace with random alphanumeric values

Comment: Hmm, that is not too helpful unfortunately. Please copy and paste the code I provided. The error must be somewhere else in your code. The code I provided displays the page as intended with Flutter 0.10.0 and Dart 2.1.0

Comment: Could you please share what it was?